# Adding statusbar in Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, statusbar

I want to add a statusbar to my Win32 application. I found out that I can use `CreateStatusWindow` function. I works fine until I re-size my window. See a part of my block of code:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }


   CreateStatusWindow(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, _T("Welcome to SpyWindows"), hWnd, 9000);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
```

Here are two printscreens of my application main window:

[image]

What can I do to have a good status bar? (I also want to divide it in more areas)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760728.aspx#Size_and_Height) mentions that the status bar will recompute its appropriate position and size when it receives a [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx) message:

> The window procedure automatically adjusts the size of the status bar
>   whenever it receives a `WM_SIZE` message. Typically, when the size of
>   the parent window changes, the parent sends a `WM_SIZE` message to the
>   status bar.

So, the simplest way to achieve this is to relay to the status bar the `WM_SIZE` messages received by the parent (with [SendMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx), from its window procedure). The message parameters do not matter, as the status bar does not use them in its computations.